# What Windows software can I use to tell which codecs are used in a video?

Tags: windows, video

I've got a small electronic device that records video as a secondary function.Though I can play that video back on most things, some editing software seems to have trouble loading it properly. I suspect this is down to an unusual video format being used, or a problem codec on my PCs. To narrow this down I'd like to see exactly what codecs/formats/wrappers are being used.

Last time I did this sort of thing I used the [GSpot Codec Information Appliance](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) but it looks like that hasn't been updated for years and is no longer actively developed or supported. Some of GSpot's feature were just [how much info it gives](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/v26x/ss_main.html) and in so much detail, the fact that it's a tiny "portable" no-install-needed executable, and identifying video details was as simple as drag-and-dropping the video onto Gspot's window and then waiting a few seconds for analysis.

What I'm looking for is:

- Software for Windows (works on 64-bit Win 8.1 preferred, but I do have access to 32-bit Win7 too if there are compatibility problems).
- Gives detailed information on video/audio codecs/formats/wrappers, framerates, sizes, etc
- Lists possibly compatible locally installed codecs, with options to test them

Nice to have:

- Flags about possible corruptions in the file
- Cheap or Free (not worried about whether it's open source or not)
- Small
- 'portable' ie no install needed

Comment: [VLC](http://superuser.com/a/348161/137286) fulfills all requirements except for the one to list compatible locally installed codecs (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Use [ffprobe and ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

- Shows every possible detail » (*codecs/formats/wrappers, framerates, sizes, etc*)
- Free, small, portable
- Lists installed codecs with `ffmpeg -codecs`

<sup>I don't know if there is a possibily to show possible corruptions in the file</sup>

#### Command

> C:\ffprobe.exe -loglevel quiet -unit -prefix -sexagesimal -show_format -show_streams -print_format flat=h=0 C:\testvideo.mp4

#### Example Output

```
stream.0.index=0
stream.0.codec_name="h264"
stream.0.codec_long_name="H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10"
stream.0.profile="High"
stream.0.codec_type="video"
stream.0.codec_time_base="1/180000"
stream.0.codec_tag_string="avc1"
stream.0.codec_tag="0x31637661"
stream.0.width=1920
stream.0.height=1080
stream.0.has_b_frames=0
stream.0.sample_aspect_ratio="0:1"
stream.0.display_aspect_ratio="0:1"
stream.0.pix_fmt="yuv420p"
stream.0.level=40
stream.0.color_range="N/A"
stream.0.color_space="unknown"
stream.0.color_transfer="unknown"
stream.0.color_primaries="unknown"
stream.0.chroma_location="left"
stream.0.timecode="N/A"
stream.0.id="N/A"
stream.0.r_frame_rate="30/1"
stream.0.avg_frame_rate="8685000/290291"
stream.0.time_base="1/90000"
stream.0.start_pts=0
stream.0.start_time="0:00:00.000000"
stream.0.duration_ts=580582
stream.0.duration="0:00:06.450911"
stream.0.bit_rate="17.033355 Mbit/s"
stream.0.max_bit_rate="N/A"
stream.0.bits_per_raw_sample="8"
stream.0.nb_frames="193"
stream.0.nb_read_frames="N/A"
stream.0.nb_read_packets="N/A"
stream.0.disposition.default=1
stream.0.disposition.dub=0
stream.0.disposition.original=0
stream.0.disposition.comment=0
stream.0.disposition.lyrics=0
stream.0.disposition.karaoke=0
stream.0.disposition.forced=0
stream.0.disposition.hearing_impaired=0
stream.0.disposition.visual_impaired=0
stream.0.disposition.clean_effects=0
stream.0.disposition.attached_pic=0
stream.0.tags.rotate="90"
stream.0.tags.creation_time="2014-12-04 09:46:15"
stream.0.tags.language="eng"
stream.0.tags.handler_name="VideoHandle"
stream.0.tags.encoder="                               "
stream.1.index=1
stream.1.codec_name="aac"
stream.1.codec_long_name="AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)"
stream.1.profile="LC"
stream.1.codec_type="audio"
stream.1.codec_time_base="1/48000"
stream.1.codec_tag_string="mp4a"
stream.1.codec_tag="0x6134706d"
stream.1.sample_fmt="fltp"
stream.1.sample_rate="48 KHz"
stream.1.channels=2
stream.1.channel_layout="stereo"
stream.1.bits_per_sample=0
stream.1.id="N/A"
stream.1.r_frame_rate="0/0"
stream.1.avg_frame_rate="0/0"
stream.1.time_base="1/48000"
stream.1.start_pts=0
stream.1.start_time="0:00:00.000000"
stream.1.duration_ts=324608
stream.1.duration="0:00:06.762667"
stream.1.bit_rate="110.594000 Kbit/s"
stream.1.max_bit_rate="N/A"
stream.1.bits_per_raw_sample="N/A"
stream.1.nb_frames="317"
stream.1.nb_read_frames="N/A"
stream.1.nb_read_packets="N/A"
stream.1.disposition.default=1
stream.1.disposition.dub=0
stream.1.disposition.original=0
stream.1.disposition.comment=0
stream.1.disposition.lyrics=0
stream.1.disposition.karaoke=0
stream.1.disposition.forced=0
stream.1.disposition.hearing_impaired=0
stream.1.disposition.visual_impaired=0
stream.1.disposition.clean_effects=0
stream.1.disposition.attached_pic=0
stream.1.tags.creation_time="2014-12-04 09:46:15"
stream.1.tags.language="eng"
stream.1.tags.handler_name="SoundHandle"
format.filename="C:\\testvideo.mp4"
format.nb_streams=2
format.nb_programs=0
format.format_name="mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2"
format.format_long_name="QuickTime / MOV"
format.start_time="0:00:00.000000"
format.duration="0:00:06.763000"
format.size="13.833356 Mbyte"
format.bit_rate="16.363573 Mbit/s"
format.probe_score=100
format.tags.major_brand="isom"
format.tags.minor_version="0"
format.tags.compatible_brands="isom3gp4"
format.tags.creation_time="2014-12-04 09:46:15"
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaInfo size 12MB 32bit or 64bit

http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

The MediaInfo data display includes:

Container: format, profile, commercial name of the format, duration, overall bit rate, writing application and library, title, author, director, album, track number, date, duration...

Video: format, codec id, aspect, frame rate, bit rate, color space, chroma subsampling, bit depth, scan type, scan order...

Audio: format, codec id, sample rate, channels, bit depth, language, bit rate...

Text: format, codec id, language of subtitle...

Chapters: count of chapters, list of chapters...

MediaInfo analyticals include:

Container: MPEG-4, QuickTime, Matroska, AVI, MPEG-PS (including unprotected DVD), MPEG-TS (including unprotected Blu-ray), MXF, GXF, LXF, WMV, FLV, Real...

Tags: Id3v1, Id3v2, Vorbis comments, APE tags...

Video: MPEG-1/2 Video, H.263, MPEG-4 Visual (including DivX, XviD), H.264/AVC, Dirac...

Audio: MPEG Audio (including MP3), AC3, DTS, AAC, Dolby E, AES3, FLAC...

Subtitles: CEA-608, CEA-708, DTVCC, SCTE-20, SCTE-128, ATSC/53, CDP, DVB Subtitle, Teletext, SRT, SSA, ASS, SAMI...

download link select the one that says "without installer" for portable
http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows

Also

Installedcodec size: 66KB portable 32bit and 64bit available

InstalledCodec is a small utility displays the list of all Codec drivers and DirectShow filters currently installed on your system. For each component the following information is displayed: Display Name, Type, Disabled Status, Installed/Modified Time, Description, Company Name, Filename, and more... 
It allows you to easily disable or enable any Codec/DirectShow component or export the list into text/xml/html file.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html